# Left Join and Where Clause

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Query -

```
Select * FROM tbl1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON  tbl1.id   = tbl2.id 
                     AND tbl2.col2 = 'zyx' 
                     AND tbl2.col3  = 'abc' 
WHERE tbl1.col1 = 'pqr'
```

Here I'm doing left outer join and using 'and' along with join.
(First I was using joins 'and' part in 'where' but my results were not correct)

My query, which is very similar to this, runs for a long time; it takes at least 10 seconds to run.  Is there a way to optimize these types of query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tbl1_1_id ON tbl1 (col1, id)
CREATE INDEX ix_tbl2_2_3_id ON tbl2 (col2, col3, id)
```

If `id` is a `CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY` in the corresponding tables, you can omit it from the index, since it will be implicitly included there anyway:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tbl1_1 ON tbl1 (col1)
CREATE INDEX ix_tbl2_2_3 ON tbl2 (col2, col3)
```

Comment: two indexes made it 3 seconds faster

Answer (score 1):

You could add indices on those columns on which you compare values.

Answer (score 1):

At first, it seems like you should put

```
AND tbl2.col2 = 'zyx' and tbl2.col3 = 'abc'
```

into the WHERE clause, however that would conflict with the OUTER JOIN. WHERE restricts the results so adding that effectively makes it an inner join. A couple of different ways to write this might be:

Add nulls to the where

```
Select * FROM tbl1      
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id      
WHERE tbl1.col1 = 'pqr' 
  AND ((tbl2.col2 = 'zyx' AND tbl2.col3 = 'abc') 
    OR (tbl2.col2 = NULL AND tbl2.col3 = NULL))
```

or use a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1          
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl2
  WHERE tbl2.col2 = 'zyx' and tbl2.col3 = 'abc'
) AS temp2 ON tbl1.id = temp2.id          
WHERE tbl1.col1 = 'pqr'
```

I would probably opt for the subquery approach as it's just clearer what you're intent is. As far as performance, any column in a WHERE should typically be covered by an index. Beyond that, the optimizer should be able to find the best approach no matter which way that you write the query.

Comment: Some options, time to fire up and look the query plans for each looking for bad stuff :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

```
Select * FROM tbl1, tbl2
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.id 
AND tbl1.col1 = 'pqr' 
AND tbl2.col2 = 'zyx' 
AND tb2.col3 = 'abc'
```

Comment: Why? And create indexes, will be very fast

Comment: NO NOT associative joins PLEASE, this makes the SELECT and WHERE sequence dependant.

Comment: because it will not return all records